# How to automatically do line break in <pre> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to put a code snippet in my React application, what strange is no matter what I do, there is no line break in the snippet. Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Hello.scss';

const Hello = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                Hello world!
            </div>
            <pre>
                npx create-react-app my-app
                cd my-app
                npm start
            </pre>
        </>
    )
}

export default Hello;
```

```css
pre {
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

I was expecting what's in the `pre` tag to be

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Instead I get:

```
npx create-react-app my-app cd my-app npm start
```

Any idea how I can make the `pre` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly provide line breaks either by using string as `children` or by forcing `{'\n'}` at the line ends.

```js
const Hello = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                Hello world!
            </div>
            <pre children={`npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
`} />
<pre>
npx create-react-app my-app{'\n'}
cd my-app{'\n'}
npm start{'\n'}
</pre>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('hello'))
```

```css
pre {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Why does this fiddle work without providing line breaks? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/8FGEL/

Comment: This fiddle doesn't use babel and jsx. It is plain html.

Comment: Why does it not work in React? I thought whatever works in plain HTML would work in React. Also it is a huge pain to add <br /> to each line. Imagine there are 50 lines

Comment: JSX is not HTML it is another syntax for function calls. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCwEICcCmBDA1hGAXhgAoAeABywD4AoMCgDxmC2ykwFo3gpPsKFGAFsAnv0EBvAOQAdMNIC-tYABMR4gRRnyl9CsJjRs6KDoXKyAeiqZqASlorw0eCAw58RUpRr7mrDgc3Di8EkJi4SrqkVr6hsamtNa2DrRAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.12.3&externalPlugins=

Comment: I haven't recommended you to manually add line breaks. :) You could use a function for that. Or a string literal that preserves the line breaks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on using string literal to preserve the line breaks?

Comment: Check the first example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`<pre>` tag works well with `<br>` tag when it comes to line break.
Meaning you can insert `<br />` tag and to do this you would need to replace the `\n` symbols by `<br />` tags.

so the html code should be like this :

```
<pre>
    npx create-react-app my-app<br />
    cd my-app<br />
    npm start<br />
</pre>
```